# Problem with accessing a class in WPF MainWindow.xaml.cs

Tags: c#, wpf

I created a class in WPF project and when I want to create a instance of that class in MainWindow.xaml.cs it doesn't recognize the class.

Here is my class:

```
namespace WPF___Data_Binding_practice.Data
{
    class Person
    {
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I created the class in a folder, can it be the reason why it doesn't recognize it? The folder name is "Data"

[image]

I tried recreating it. But always same problem.
I am writing my code from a tutorial video and doing the exact same things.

Comment: You'll need to tell mainwindow about the namespace the class is in. You do that with a using statement up the top of your mainwindow.xam!.cs.  I would expect visual studio to be offering you the option to do that semi automatically when you try and new it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I created the class in a folder, can it be the reason why it doesn't recognize it?

Yes. When you create a folder, you can choose it for the folder to make the files inside have their own namespace (I think it's the default option) or not to have their own namespace. Classes sharing the same namespace, for example

```
namespace WPF___Data_Binding_practice
```

can  see each other, regardless of the physical file each of them is located into. But if you created a subfolder and the class in there has a different namespace:

```
namespace WPF___Data_Binding_practice.Data
```

then they are not going to see each other automatically because they belong to different namespaces.

as @Andy explained in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77483106/problem-with-accessing-a-class-in-wpf-mainwindow-xaml-cs/77484055#comment136599043_77483106), you need to reference the namespace of your class `Person` from MainWindow.xaml.cs.

In the solution explorer, click on the small triangle next to MainWindow.xaml to expand and you will see the file MainWindow.xaml.cs.

Click on MainWindow.xaml.cs, open it and add this at the top of the file (first line):

```
using WPF___Data_Binding_practice.Data;
```

Alternatively, you could also change back the namespace in Person.cs from

```
namespace WPF___Data_Binding_practice.Data
```

to

```
namespace WPF___Data_Binding_practice
```

but I think that the first option (using statement) is preferable because it's clearer to have your namespaces match with your folder structure, especially in large projects.